# CPU Overheating at boot

Tags: boot, cpu, bios, overheating

I've had this trouble for months but this time got further and senseless.
I have a DELL Latitude E6410 4GB Ram 2.40 Ghz and no battery only cord power source.

I've already had this problem before and I went to a shop to fix it and they told me that my fan got screwed up and I changed it and I still got the problem. The only fact that drivea me nuts its that the POST process shows that there's a problem with my CPU I searched for solutions and it fixed the light blinking thing but now, POST gives me another light thing about RAM malfunction.
I've tried runing the diagnostics startup but either shuts down at the start of it or shuts down mid-cores test, any idea what could the problem be?

Comment: You may want to register an account, then use the contact us link to merge this account with that. This will let you edit your own posts and do other handy things

Answer (score 0):

You can access the BIOS and check the temperature for the CPU first in order to identify CPU or RAM problem, CPU usually will automatically shutdown for around over 100 degree celsius, the heatsink of the fan may not be probably installed. You should back to the shop and ask them to fix it.